# Get Column Names Sorted by their Values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe for which I would like to create a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary will be the indices of the row, and the values will be lists of column names of the dataframe sorted by the values in that row (descending order). Consider an example below:

```
df=      23    45    12     3     6
    45   0.2   1     0.12   0.5   0.1
    12   0.5   0.2   1      0.3   0.9
    23   0.1   0.9   0.3    1     0.5
```

I would like to create a dictionary in the following form:

```
dict={ '45':['45','3','23','12','6'], 
       '12':['12','6','23','3','45'], 
       '23':['3','45','6','23']}
```

where the values are column names sorted by their values in that row. I tried the following:

```
for idx,row in df.iteritems():
    l = row.values.tolist()
    l.sort(reverse=True)
    print idx,l
```

but this gives me the values and not the column names sorted in descending order. Any help on how I can produce the desired result will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this seems to work:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 10, 50], 'B': [2, -8, 3, 7], 'C': [1, 10, -20, 1]})

>>> dict([(r[0], list(df.columns[np.argsort(list(r)[1: ])])) \
    for r in list(df.to_records())])
{0: ['A', 'C', 'B'],
 1: ['B', 'A', 'C'],
 2: ['C', 'B', 'A'],
 3: ['C', 'B', 'A']}
```

**Explanation:**

- `list(df.to_records())` is a list of rows as tuples.
- `r[0]` is the first element in the tuple.
- `list(r)[1: ]` is the rest of the tuple.
- `np.argsort` returns the indices of an array according to the sorted value order.
- `dict(`list_of_pairs`)` creates a dictionary from an array of pairs.

Comment: Thanks, your solution almost solves my problem. Just one more step remaining..I need the column names sorted in descending order, so I will have to use `np.argsort(list(r)[1: ])[::-1]` instead of `np.argsort(list(r)[1: ])`. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: I would also add that using `iterrows()` is faster. I compared using both functions on a DataFame of 14939 rows by 14939 columns of `int` values. You just have to adjust the formula as following: `dict([(r[0], list(df.columns[np.argsort(list(r)[1])])) for r in list(df.iterrows())])` It took around 30 seconds when using `itterrows()`, and around 280 seconds when using `to_records()`.